# Painting chipped surfaces

Tags: ceiling

I have a question regarding painting some chipped ceilings. I have a really old house, and it's been painted several times before I got it. A couple of rooms in my home have LARGE spots of the ceiling that have chipped, exposing the primer coat, or possibly the first coat ever applied, underneath. I am talking large spots, like 4'x4' areas.

What is the best way to re-paint these? I assume just painting over the whole ceiling, it would still be visible through the paint. Does the whole ceiling need to be scraped and repainted, or do I need to sand down the edges of the chip so that it's smooth and level, then apply the paint?

One of these ceilings is a knock-down stucco texture (It looks like somebody used a trowel to apply texture to the ceiling, then knocked it down), so it may be extremely difficult to repair.

Comment: It's important to understand why the paint is missing. I wouldn't describe areas that large as "chips". Is the entire area coming loose?

Comment: I understand what you're describing, I've encountered the same. I can tell you from experience that both ideas (just painting over, or trying to smooth the edges and then painting) you *will* still be able to see the depression afterwards. The human eye is annoyingly good at noticing when light isn't falling evenly on a surface because of pits/craters, no matter how shallow they are. If you don't want this to irritate you, you have to fill them, but I'm not sure what the best product would be or whether you need to scrape additional paint first, so just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @isherwood The entire area didn't really come 'loose'. A small part of the ceiling was 'bubbling', so I went on to the ceiling with a scraper to scrape the loose bits off. As I did that, it spread into the larger piece that it is now. Since then, no other pieces have lifted or peeled.

The surface underneath looks clean, there is no sign of water damage, I just don't think it adhered very good to begin with. My attic is also directly above both rooms, and the climate difference between the attic and the two rooms is huge, so I think maybe that had something to do with that with old paint